# Doubt regarding an approach to derive the potential energy of two parallel dipoles

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential-energy, dipole-moment

For a system of two dipoles of dipole moment $|\vec{p}| = p = qd$ each, separated by a distance r, parallel to each other, the Potential Energy of the system comes out to be $ kp^2/r^3$ when calculated using the standard method (separating point charges, taking and adding potential energy of pairs of charges, excluding pair of charges on the same dipole) as follows:
$$ U = {2kq^2 \over r} - {2kq^2\over\sqrt{r^2+d^2}} = {2kq^2\over r }\left(1-\left(1+{d^2\over r^2}\right)^{-1/2} \right)$$ assuming $d \ll r$ and applying binomial theorem for any index (neglecting higher powers),
$$ U= {2kq^2\over r}\left({d^2\over 2r^2}\right) = {kp^2\over r^3}$$

Now, we know that the potential energy of a dipole in a uniform electric field $\vec{E}$ is given by $-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{E}$ (derived by rotating dipole in the field and using torque on it and assuming potential energy of dipole is zero when it is perpendicular to the external field), looking at one dipole, due to its small size, the field around it is nearly uniform and equal to $kp/r^3$ opposite to the direction of dipole, so according to the formula, the potential energy of the dipole should be equal to $kp^2/ r^3$. Similarly, its $kp^3/r^3$ for another dipole. So the total potential energy of the system should be the sum, $2kp^2/r^3$. But it is not matching the expression from the standard method.
 
So, what is the exact problem with the second approach? If its just because of our assumption of uniform field, ain't the coming of potential energy exactly double a big deviation? Or I am missing something else? (I personally feel something is wrong with the last step of adding the energies, is there something related to the principle of superposition?)
Also, please explain precisely, why do we exclude the potential energy of charges on the same dipole?

Comment: *applying binomial theorem for any index (neglecting higher powers* - do you mean Taylor expansion in $d/r$?

Comment: [link](https://www.cuemath.com/jee/rational-indices-binomial-theorem/) I am referring to this. Here x is d^2/r^2 and since it is a very small value, its further powers will be neglible against it. Although I don't know Taylor expansion precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential energy is the energy needed to construct the system "from scratch", with the particles starting from infinitely far away. By assuming the field of the other dipole is fixed and constant, you are essentially computing the energy needed to move one dipole through a constant field to its final location (and then doubling this answer). This is different from the energy needed to bring two dipoles near each other. In essence, by assuming a constant field, your calculation overestimates the field that the second dipole would experience as you bring it from infinity to a distance $r$ from the first dipole.

In fact, you would find the same problem if you applied your method to monopoles, which might be a simpler case to consider. The potential energy needed to assemble a system of two monopoles with charge $q$ a distance $r$ apart is of course
\begin{equation}
\frac{k q^2}{r}
\end{equation}
If you were to consider the energy of two dipoles in a constant electric field, that would be
\begin{equation}
2 q E
\end{equation}
Setting $E=k q/r$ would yield
\begin{equation}
\frac{2 k q^2}{r}
\end{equation}
with the same factor of $2$ you are finding in your dipole example. The issue is simply that assembling two charges in a constant electric field (ignoring their mutual interaction) is a different problem from assembling two charges that are repelling each other.

Comment: _By assuming the field of the other dipole is fixed and constant, you are essentially computing the energy needed to move one dipole through a constant field to its final location (and then doubling this answer)._ I am not, while using the formula U = -P.E , moving the dipole, because the formula was derived by rotating the dipole at one place, isn't it so?

Comment: And your point of monopoles, we are considering the potential due to one point charge, we don't double it up there because we fix one monoplole at a point in space and bring the other from infinite, right? So I understand now with dipoles this is the reason we shouldn't double the energy, am I correct? And the point of not including the potential energy of charges on same dipoles, how is it justified if we build dipoles from scratch?

Comment: @Harshil Actually this factor of $2$ might just be the famous double counting factor, see eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/497622/why-is-there-a-1-2-in-the-expression-for-electrostatic-energy-u

Comment: Yes that could be the factor behind this, but I don't get how can we correlate this energy of dipoles directly with that. Actually your answer helps in understanding how could this approach of using the formula maybe incorrect, but I don't get the precise thing in here. A more mathematical approach would help understand better... (To add, I still couldn't get the point of not including the potential energy of charges on same dipole)

Comment: @Harshil If you take your approach of splitting the dipole into point charges, and we ignore the interaction between charges within one dipole, then the resolution is quite simple. The total energy is *one half* times the sum of each charge times the potential at the location at the charge (because of the double counting factor). That will lead you to the exact calculation you did in your question, but with an extra $1/2$ out in front. In other words, you are right the energies don't simply add; you also need to divide by $2$. I'll write this up a bit more carefully later.